# What GOARCH to set for my webapp written in Go?

Tags: go, deployment

I want to deploy my webapp (basically CRUD) on DigitalOcean or a similar cloud provider. I found out that I can set `GOARCH=386` or `GOARCH=amd64`. Both build properly on my computer.

How do I decide which one I need to deploy on server? There are all popular options like latest Ubuntu, Debian, CentOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the one that matches the architecture of your droplet. You can view this on your  droplets list. Note that targeting the `386` platform you can run it on both `386` and `amd64` platforms, while compiling to `amd64` you can only run it on `amd64`.

If you're asking which to choose, then it's up to you. Know that some operations are faster on `amd64` (especially those which use / involve 64-bit values like `int64`), and also some features of the Go tool are only available if you target the `amd64` architecture, for example the [race detector](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html), [Supported Systems](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html#Supported_Systems):

> The race detector runs on `darwin/amd64`, `freebsd/amd64`, `linux/amd64`, and `windows/amd64`.

Executable binary size and memory usage is somewhat bigger for `amd64`, but it's not really an issue in case of Go, as a simple, running Go web server uses like 8 MB of memory. Unless you use excessively large arrays / slices like `[big_number]int` of course, as the size of `int` will be 4 bytes on `386` and 8 bytes on `amd64`.

Comment: Should then I in general case just choose amd64, deploy on a amd64 platform and don't think about it ever?

Comment: @SergeiBasharov Yeah, that's what I'd do.